# Coordinates of perpendicular points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I would like to draw a rectangle made of Mesh.

I enter the **A** starting point and **B** ending point.

The width of the rectangle is known in advance and is equal to **H**.

How to correctly determine the coordinates of corner points? (*Everything happens in 3D*)

There are a lot of theoretical entries on the net (but mostly for 2D) and trying something like this:

```
var vAB = B - A;
var P1 = new Vector3(-vAB.z, vAB.y, vAB.x) / Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(vAB.x, 2) + Mathf.Pow(vAB.y, 2) + Mathf.Pow(vAB.z, 2)) * 0.5 * H;
```

But I can't find the correct solution

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick explanation of the trig involved. There are other tools which will reduce the boilerplate a bit, but this should give you an understanding of the underlying maths.

I've tweaked your problem statement slightly: I'm just showing the XY plane (there's no Z involved), and I've rotated it so that the line AB forms a positive angle with the horizontal (as it makes explaining the maths a bit easier). A is at (x1, y1), B is at (x2, y2).

[image: Rotated]

The first step is to find the angle θ that the line AB makes with the horizontal. Draw a right-angled triangle, where AB is the hypotenuse, and the other two sides are parallel to the X and Y axes:

[image: Right-angled triangle]

You can see that the horizontal side has length (x2 - x1), and the vertical side has length (y2 - y1). The angle between the base and the hypotenuse (the line AB) is given by trig, where `tan θ = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)`, so `θ = arctan((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1))`.

(Make sure you use the [`Math.Atan2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.atan2?view=net-5.0) method to calculate this angle, as it makes sure the sign of θ is correct).

Next we'll look at the corner P1, which is connected to A. As before, draw a triangle with the two shorter sides being parallel at the X and Y axes:

[image: Triangle with P1]

This again forms a right-angled triangle with hypotenuse `H/2`. To find the base of the triangle, which is the X-distance between P1 and A, again use trig: `H/2 * sin θ`. Similarly, the Y-distance between P1 and A is `H/2 cos θ`. Therefore `P1 = (x1 + H/2 sin θ, y2 - H/2 cos θ)`.

Repeat the same trick for the other 3 corners, and you'll find the same result, but with differing signs.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way should be to use the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). The cross product of two vectors is perpendicular to both input vectors. You will need to define the normal of your rectangle, In this I use `vector3.up`. `A-B` cannot be parallel to the normal vector, or you will get an invalid result.

```
var l = B - A;
var s = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(l, Vector3.up));
var p1 = A + s * h/2;
var p2 = A - s * h/2;
var p3 = B - s * h/2;
var p4 = B + s * h/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach requires you to use a `Transform`.

```
public Transform ht; // assign in inspector or create new

void calculatePoints(Vector3 A, Vector3 B, float H)
{
    Vector3 direction = B - A;
    ht.position = A;
    ht.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction, Vector3.Up);
    
    Vector3 P1 = new Vector3(A + ht.right * H/2f);
    Vector3 P2 = new Vector3(A + ht.left * H/2f);
    Vector3 P3 = new Vector3(B + ht.right * H/2f);
    Vector3 P4 = new Vector3(B + ht.left * H/2f);
}
```

I think it's intuitive to think with "left" and "right" which is why I used the Transform. If you wanted to define a point along the way, you'd be using `ht.forward * value` added to `A`, where `value` would be something between `0` and `direction.magnitude`.

Comment: you have a typo: `B + ht.right` two times.